# How to use the multiselect feature in open file dialog box

Tags: vb.net

What code will I put in the open file dialog box_fileok if the multi select feature is enabled.
I currently have this code, but it only shows in the textbox the last file that has been selected.

```
  Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = OpenFileDialog3.OpenFile()
        TextBox3.Text = OpenFileDialog3.FileName.ToString()
        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
            //insert code to read the file data
            strm.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Done!")
        End If
```

Comment: What is OpenFileDialog3 ? The .net class is just OpenFileDialog

Comment: @John - an instance of the class, of course.

Comment: Then you need to fix your instance. OpenFileDialog doesn't have a `FileName` method, It only has `File` and `Files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FileNames property. It returns a string array containing all selected files.

```
TextBox3.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, OpenFileDialog3.FileNames)
' Displays each filename on a separate line
```